# Retrieve regular expression results with in-depth info

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there a way to retrieve regular expression object that contains the start position of the match, end position, total length etc.?

Or at least something like `String.search(/pattern/)`, but with more than one result.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) is what you're looking for I'd say.

Edit:

for example (and using the code from the linked page):

```
var re = /d(b+)(d)/ig;  
var result = re.exec("cdbBdbsbz");
```

- `result.index` is the start position
- `re.lastIndex` is the end position
- `result[0].length` is the total length

Comment: `console.log(/\s/g.exec('The lorem ipsum paragraph everyone\'s familiar with..'));` returns only one element inside the array with no extra properties. My guess would be that it's intended and I have to iterate all over the place to get my results, right?

Comment: Yeah you have to iterate over it if you want such a detailed result, or you'll use the match metod of the string, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match but this one only provides an array with the matches, and no further details.

Answer (score 2):

You could roll your own function based on exec, here is an example that builds a result object including index of all matches...

```
searchAll = function (text,pattern) {
  var result, output = [];
  while((result = pattern.exec(text)) != null) {
    output.push({
      result:result[0],
      index:result.index,
      lastIndex:pattern.lastIndex
    })
  }
  return output
}

var s = searchAll("JavaScript is more fun than Java!",/Java/g)

alert( JSON.stringify( s ) )
```